# how can i use `#function` symbol in a `inline` function?

Tags: swift

I'd like to use the name of function to resolve some problems, but `#function` seems not to work well with `@inline(__always)`, here is my codes:

```
@inline(__always) func log() {
  print(#function)
}
func a() { log() } // want 'a()', but got 'log()'
func b() { log() }
func c() { log() }
//...
```

Can anybody explain? or that's just a stupid idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your intention is to print the name of the function which calls
`log()`, then you should pass it as default argument (which is evaluated
in the context of the caller), as demonstrated
in  [Building `assert()` in Swift, Part 2: `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=15) in the Swift blog.

Example:

```
@inline(__always) func log(_ message: String, callingFunction: String = #function) {
    print("\(callingFunction): \(message)")
}

func a() { log("Hello world") }
func b() { log("Foo") }
func c() { log("Bar") }

a() // a(): Hello world
b() // b(): Foo
c() // c(): Bar
```

This works regardless of whether the `log` function is inlined or not.
(Inlining does not change the semantics of a program. In particular,
it does not mean that the source code of `func log` is included from
the source code of `func a()` and compiled as a single function.)

Comment: But inline @inline attributes are ignored in debug builds (when optimizations are turned off). Could you explain pls why we could use you're code in playground or debug builds?

Comment: Yes, that's the way i have solved problem finally, what i was confused at is, it is supposed to be each function's name, right? because we have a 
 `@inline(__always)` symbol here, did i misunderstand the concept of `inline`?. Sorry for my poor English, i am not a native speaker...

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk: OP wants a log function which prints the name of its calling function, and that is how it works. It does not matter if the function is inlined or not.

Comment: @jianstm: `@inline` does not change the semantics of a Swift program. The compiler (may) inline the log function in the *compiled code.* But the program still behaves as if there are two separate functions, one calling the other. (Otherwise the behaviour of functions could depend on whether the compiler chooses to inline or not.)